# Mule JDBCConnector not setting null values

Tags: mule

I have configured a JDBConnector which inserts data into a database. The values for the query parameters come from a map returned from a custom transformer. However, even  when the map value is null, Mule returns a NullPayload and the table ends up with nothing in that column.

```
<jdbc:connector database-ref="myDatasource" ...>
<jdbc:query key="insertData" value="insert into myTable values(#[message.payload.key])"/>
</jdbc:connector>
```

How can I force Mule to insert null when the actual value in the map is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the map value is null, it's expected that the column will contain no value after insertion.

Comment: But I should expect the value of null in the column field of that database table. If I insert null in a insert statement with plain JDBC, it will show up as null not blank which has no meaning in SQL terms.

Comment: There is just whitespace in the column not null, which is incorrect

Comment: Oh this is what you meant by "nothing" in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, underlying information is XMl and the text nodes are being returned when encountered, simply filtering out the text nodes fixed the problem.